# Why do I get a missing operator when using SET /a in Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

My line of code is:

```
SET /A 327761=%RANDOM% * 1000 / 32768 + 1
```

And I'm just getting a missing operator error. I don't see how this could be and other questions on here don't help.

Comment: Don't use numbers as variable names

Comment: set /a "random = 327761 * 1000 / 32768 + 1"

Comment: `SET /A WORDSTRING=%RANDOM% * 1000 / 32768 + 1`

Comment: @access_granted, it's not a good idea to set variable `RANDOM` as it is a system-reserved name of a pseudo-variable that returns a random number on the range `[0,32768[`...

Comment: @achipfl: oopsie, did not know that, so then Compo's example is superior.

Answer (score 0):

Because nobody decided to post an answer, here it is, thanks to @SomethingDark

You can't have just numbers as variable names. So I added a character `C` to the start of the variable.

Comment: A simple Google Search yields your answer, https://ss64.com/nt/set.html. Avoid starting variable names with a number, this will avoid the variable being mis-interpreted as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

While it is a bad idea to name a variable starting with a number, the usual problem araises when trying to retrieve the value, not when you set it. That is, there is not any problem in doing

```
set "1234=some value"
```

You will have later problems retrieving the value because `%1234%` is parsed as `%1` (first argument to batch file) followed by the string `234%`

But as said, you can set the value. So, why something like `set /a "1234=1+1"` raises an error?

The reason is that the commands in `cmd` are first parsed to determine the command to execute, but in some cases, once the command has been identified, the rest of the work is delegated to a command specific parser. `for` command is one example of this behaviour, but `set /a` also has its own parser.

This `set /a` parser does not only handle the `var=value` syntax. You can also do things like

```
 set /a 123+123
```

to retrieve the result of the calc not storing it anywhere.

The `set /a` parser handles its parameters as a sequence of numeric/arithmetic/logic/bit/assignment operands/operators. The `=` is just an assignment operator, and this operator needs the operand on its left side to be a variable name.

The problem is that the `set /a` parser gives precedence to the numeric operands over the variable names: if it starts with a number, it is a number operand. In your case, `set /a 327761=....`, the `327761` literal is handled as a numeric operand, not as a variable name, and the assignment operator can not assign a value to another value.