# Can't use set /a in batch

Tags: batch-file, subtraction

with this script I would like to make `%now-year%-%eta-year%`, but the result is:

> Missing operators

How can I fix it?

```
set eta-year=%nascita-ok:~6,4%
set eta-month=%nascita-ok:~3,2%
set eta-day=%nascita-ok:~0,2%

if %eta-month:~0,1%==0 set eta-month=%eta-month:~1,2%
if %eta-day:~0,1%==0 set eta-day=%eta-day:~1,2%


set now-year=%date:~6,4%
set now-month=%date:~3,2%
set now-day=%date:~0,2%

if %now-month:~0,1%==0 set now-month=%now-month:~1,2%
if %now-day:~0,1%==0 set now-day=%now-day:~1,2%


set /a eta-year-ok=%now-year%-%eta-year%
set /a eta-month-ok=%now-month%-%eta-month%
set /a eta-day-ok=%now-day%-%eta-day%
```

Comment: [Different case, same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44325170/2861476). The `set /a` parser interprets your variables names as arithmetic operations. Try replacing `-` with `_`

Comment: Sorry, i didn't write that, I want to make an arithmetic operation...

Comment: He's saying to change the variable names to not include `-`s.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this

Comment: That worked, thanks...

Comment: also be aware of *days* or *months* being *0x* as it may be treated as octal. so it's good practice not `set eta-day=%nascita-ok:~0,2%` but `set /a "eta_day=1%nascita-ok:~0,2%-100"`